# Datatable rows.count == 0 gives 1 although there not found records in the table

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I have a problem and I don't know why it's happening!

I am trying to find Max value in a column inside the database table, I use this code:

```
private void FrmCustomer_New_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int NewID;           
    DataTable _Dt = CusVar.GetCustomersIDs();
    if (_Dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        NewID = 1;
        this.txt1.Text = NewID.ToString();
        DataRow _Row = CusVar.GetCustomersIDs().Rows[0];
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(_Dt.Rows[0]["MaxID"]));
    }
}
```

the code is working but it gives 1 although there are no records in the table?
I use C# and Access database ACCDB.

I use this function in Cls_Customers:

```
public DataTable GetCustomersIDs()
{
    DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
    DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
    Dt = DAL.DataSelect("Select Max(CustomerID) AS MaxID From TblCustomers", null);
    DAL.CloseConn();
    return Dt;
}
```

what is the problem, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query:

```
Select Max(CustomerID) AS MaxID
From TblCustomers
```

It is an aggregation query.  Aggregation queries with no `group by` always return one row -- regardless of whether any rows match.

The value returned in the single row is `NULL` for `MaxId`.

I am highly suspicious of what you want to do.  If you want the maximum id -- and no rows if the table is empty -- then do:

```
select c.CustomerID
from TblCustomers c
order by c.CustomerID desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

(This uses ANSI/ISO standard syntax so the exact logic might depend on your database.)

My suspicion is that you then want to use this id for an `insert` -- and that is a bad approach.  Almost all databases support some sort of auto-incremented column (with syntax elements such as `auto_increment`, `serial`, or `identity`).  That is the right way to assign a unique incrementing id to a column in a table.

Comment: I want to find Max value that already exists in the "CustomerId" column to give new Id for the new record according to that.

Comment: and first of all, I want to check if there are no records in the table then I will give 1 for the first inserted record. Please help me how I can use the SQL sentence that you gave me?

Comment: @M.J - doing this on the C# side is a *terrible* idea. Even if you can guarantee that exactly one person at a time will be attempting to add a new customer. Re-read the last paragraph of Gordon's answer.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - Any help?

Comment: @M.J . . I upvoted Damien's comment.  You should be using an `identity`/`serial`/`auto_increment` column.  You should not be doing this at the application level.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , it's ok but please explain to me more why?

Comment: @M.J - Single-user applications are *rare*. Have you considered what happens if two (or more) users use this code at the same time? I.e. they both get the max, they then both add 1, they then both give *identical "new" numbers* for two different customers. Better to rely on a mechanism in the database that (whatever other perceived issues may exist) guarantee not to issue the *same number twice*.

Comment: @M.J - and even if this *is* currently a single-user system - do you really want to have to explain why the application *cannot* be used by multiple users simultaneously as/when the organisation grows?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Sql query might be returning null and if there are no rows that match the criteria.

If the intention is to find the number of rows returned.Change the sql query to return the count instead of using aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:
SELECT MAX(T1.CustomerID) AS MaxID From TblCustomers T1